# Create a Fast Sin() function to improve fps ? Fast sin() function?

Tags: c++, c, performance, math, trigonometry

I am rendering 500x500 points in real-time. 
I have to compute the position of points using atan() and sin() functions. By using atan() and sin() I am getting **24 fps** (frames per second).

```
float thetaC = atan(value);
float h = (value) / (sin(thetaC)));
```

If I don't use sin() I am getting **52 fps**.

and if I dont use atan() I am **30 fps**.

So, the big problem is with sin(). How can I use Fast Sin version. Can I create a Look Up Table for that ? I don't have any specific values to create LUT. what can I do in this situation ?

***PS: I have also tried fast sin function of ASM but not getting any difference.***

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the trig functions use a lookup table natively.

Comment: Make sure you test without `sin` but keeping the _division_

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Not necessarily and you may not know for sure what the CPU does internally while executing `FSIN` or `FSINCOS`.

Comment: Without being an incredibly coarse approximation, I'd be amazed if you could write anything that was faster. If you're running on an x86 system, most likely it already compiles to using the fsin function on the FPU already, which is as fast as it's going to get.

Comment: K-ballo I have tried verything. with division without , with multiplicatin without. etc etc. but the only matter with sin().

Comment: I worked on an audio effects driver once. One of the developers on the team presented to me his "fast sin() function" for speeding up the FFTs and other DSP equations. He had every intent of checking it in.  When I benchmarked it, I found it much slower than the native C runtime and less accurate. It would have made the driver slower and the audio output worse.

Comment: Have you thought about moving your code onto the GPU?

Comment: @selbie FFT and DSP equations aren't bound by `sin()` calls. All practical implementations of FFT use lookup-tables for all the twiddle factors that are needed.

Comment: @selbie....
How can I move to GPU with just one call. DO i need to use any library for that ? I can use GPU for just calculating the simple functions. I think its not possible to move my whole code to GPU. if there is way to compute just sin cos or some simple math function then it will be awesome. ?

Comment: You could always take advantage of parallel computing (*eg* OpenMP) if your pixels/points are not inter-related.  That does mean the program will perform better on multi-core machines.  Dunno if that's any use to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the accuracy that you need.  The maximum derivative of sin is 1, so if if x1 and x2 are within epsilon of one another, then sin(x1) and sin(x2) are also within epsilon.  If you just need accuracy to within, say 0.001, then you can create a lookup table of 1000 * PI = 3142 points, and just look up the value closest to the one you need.  This can be faster than what the native code does, since the native code (probably) uses a lookup table for polynomial coefficients, and then interpolates, and since this table can be small enough to stay in cache easily.

If you need complete accuracy over the whole range, then there's probably nothing better that you can do.

If you wanted, you could also create a lookup table over (1/sin(x)), since that's your actual function of interest.  Either way, you'll want to be careful around sin(x) = 0, since a small error in sin(x) can cause a big error in 1/sin(x).  Defining your error tolerance is important for figuring out what shortcuts you can take.

You'd create the lookup table with something like:

```
float *table = malloc(1000 * sizeof(float));
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  table[i] = sin(i/1000.0);
}
```

and would access it something like

```
float fastSin(float x){
  int index = x * 1000.0;
  return table[index];
}
```

This code isn't complete (and **will crash** for anything outside of 0 < x < 1, because of array bounds), but should get you started.

Comment: 0.001 this accuracy i think its ok. But how can I create LUT. can U give me an idea ?

Answer (score 11):

Hang on a second....

You have a triangle, you're computing the hypoteneuse.  First, you're taking `atan(value)` to get the angle, and then using `value` again with `sin` to compute `h`.  So we have the scenario where one side of the triangle is 1:

```
   /|
h / | value
 /  |
/C__|
  1
```

All you really need to do is calculate `h = sqrt(value*value + 1);` ...  But then, `sqrt` isn't the fastest function around either.

Perhaps I've missed the point or you've left something out.  I've always used lookup tables for `sin` and `cos`, and found them to be fast.  If you don't know the values ahead of time then you need to approximate, but this means a multiplication, truncation to integer (and possibly sign conversion) in order to get the array index.  If you can convert your units to work in integers (effectively making your floats into fixed-point), it makes the lookup even quicker.

Comment: Depending on your application, sometimes leaving everything as the squared value is okay...  Often you can avoid trigonometric functions AND square root altogether.

Comment: The invsqrt SSE instruction is insanely fast because it sacrifices full precision.

Comment: +1. This is the right answer. If replacing the code with `h=sqrt(value*value+1.0);` meets the timing requirements, there is no need to go any further. If it doesn't, an approximation of that function is the way to go.

Comment: In most cases, using trig functions in software means you're doing something wrong. This is a case in point.

Answer (score 2):

For sin (but not atan) you can actually get simpler than a table--just create

```
float sin_arr[31416]; //Or as much precision as you need
for (int i=0; i<31416; ++i)
   sin_arr[i] = sin( i / 10000.0 );

//...

float h = (value) / sin_arr[ (int)(thetaC*10000.0) % 31416 ];
```

My guess is that this will give you a speed improvement.

Comment: Um, why is this table not a table? <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh I guess I understand 'table' to be a map-like structure, with key-value pairs.  This is simpler than that.  But if standard usage calls this array a table, fine, duly noted.

Comment: I've always understood this as a table; one of my Math professors many years ago mentioned computing the sine of an angle by the "method of table lookup". <g>